# How to deserialize DynamicComposite column value?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am trying to implement a data model where row keys are Strings, column names are Longs and column values are DynamicComposites. Using Hector, an example of the stored procedure looks like this:

```
// create the value
DynamicComposite colVal = new DynamicComposite(); 
colVal.add(0, "someString");
colVal.setComparatorByPosition(0, "org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type");
colVal.setSerializerByPosition(0, StringSerializer.get());

// create the column
HColumnImpl<Long, DynamicComposite> newCol = new
    HColumnImpl<Long, DynamicComposite>(longSerializer, 
        dynamicCompositeSerializer);

newCol.setName(longValue);
newCol.setValue(colVal);
newCol.setClock(keySpace.createClock());

// insert the new column
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keySpace,stringSerializer);
mutator.addInsertion("rowKey","columnFamilyName",newCol);
mutator.execute();
```

Now, when I try to retrieve the data:

```
// create the query
SliceQuery<String,Long,DynamicComposite> sq =
    HFactory.createSliceQuery(keySpace, stringSerializer, longSerializer, 
        dynamicCompositeSerializer);

// set the query
sq.setColumnFamily("columnFamilyName");
sq.setKey("rowKey");
sq.setColumnNames(longValue);

// execute the query
QueryResult<ColumnSlice<Long, DynamicComposite>> qr = sq.execute();

// get the data
qr.get().getColumnByName(longValue).getValue();
```

or when I just try to get plain byes:

```
// get the data    
dynamicSerializer.fromByteBuffer(qr.get().
    getColumnByName(longValue).getValueBytes());
```

I run into an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableClassToInstanceMap.getInstance(ImmutableClassToInstanceMap.java:147)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.serializerForComparator(AbstractComposite.java:321)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.getSerializer(AbstractComposite.java:344)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.deserialize(AbstractComposite.java:713)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.DynamicComposite.fromByteBuffer(DynamicComposite.java:25)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.DynamicCompositeSerializer.fromByteBuffer(DynamicCompositeSerializer.java:35)
```

As far as I have understood from all the tutorials I read, it should be possible to use DynamicComposite as column value. Therefore I want to ask: what am I doing wrong? From the exception it seems I am just forgetting to set something somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Radovan,

Its probably due to compatibility issues of the Guava library used in conjuction with the  Hector version.

See also : https://github.com/hector-client/hector/pull/591

I am on Hector-core-1.1-1.jar, in combination with the Guava-14.0.jar I get the same error as you. When I use it with the Guava-12.0.1.jar however it works fine for me.